# Outputting the contents of a list of a custom data type

Tags: haskell

I have a custom data type `Movie = String Int [(String,Int)]` (Movie Name Year [(Fan,Rating)] and want to do a couple of things:

First I want to make a function that averages the Ints from the list of tuples and just outputs that number. So far I have this incomplete function:

`avgRating :: [DataType] -> Int
avgRating [(Movie a b [(fan,rating)])] = sumRatings / (length [<mylist>])`

Here I need a function sumRatings to recurse through the list and sum all the ratings, but i'm not sure where to start.

The other issue I have here is that i'm not sure what to put where `<mylist>` is as I would normally give the list a variable name and then use it there, but since I have split the list up to define other variables I can't name it.

I hope that makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a data structure defined as

```
data Movie = Movie String Int [(String, Int)]
```

While this works, it can be a bit cumbersome to work with when you have that many fields.  Instead, you can leverage type aliases and record syntax as

```
type Name = String
type Year = Int
type Rating = Int

data Movie = Movie
    { mName :: Name
    , mYear :: Year
    , mRatings :: [(Name, Rating)]
    } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Now things are a bit more explicit and easier to work with.  The `mName`, `mYear`, and `mRatings` functions will take a `Movie` and return the corresponding field from it.  Your `Movie` constructor still works in the same way too, so it won't break existing code.

To calculate the average of the ratings, you really want a function that extracts all the ratings for a movie and aggregates them into a list:

```
ratings :: Movie -> [Rating]
ratings mov = map snd $ mRatings mov
```

Then you just need an `average` function.  This will be a bit different because you can't calculate the average of `Int`s directly, you'll have to convert to a floating point type:

```
average :: [Rating] -> Float   -- Double precision isn't really needed here
average rs = fromIntegral (sum rs) / fromIntegral (length rs)
```

The `fromIntegral` function converts an `Int` to a `Float` (the actual type signature is a bit more general).  Since both the `sum` of `Int`s is an `Int` and the `length` of a list is always an `Int`, you need to convert both.

Now you can just compose these into a single function:

```
movieAvgRating :: Movie -> Float
movieAvgRating = average . ratings
```

Now, if you need to calculate the average ratings for several movies, you can apply `ratings` to each of them, aggregate them into a single list of ratings, then call `average` on that.  I would suggest looking at the `concatMap` function.  You'll be wanting to make a function like

```
moviesAvgRating :: [Movie] -> Float
moviesAvgRating movs = average $ ???
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great response! I'll only ask about the part i've got to so far: What do these {} do differently to other brackets? The name that accompanies the rating is the fan's name, so I take it I would add a new type Fan = String and make mRatings :: [(Fan,Rating)]?

Comment: @Chillo The curly braces indicate [record syntax](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses), and it's just a way of naming the fields of a constructor.  You certainly could write another `type Fan = String` if you want, that would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: The function movieAvgRating = average . ratings is confusing me a little, how do you specify the movie which is being rated? Would it not look something like `movieAvgRating mov = average (ratings mov)`? As the ratings function needs a movie input. Also, what function does the . operator serve?

Comment: The `.` operator is function composition.  Its type is `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`, so it takes two functions and glues them together.  I could have written `ratings` as `ratings = map snd . mRatings` too, they're equivalent.  It would also be equivalent to say `ratings mov = map snd . mRatings $ mov`.  The `$` operator is usually called the application operator.  You can think of it as forcing everything to its right to be evaluated then feeding it to the function on the left.  It's often confused with `.`, but it has a very different definition.  continued...

Comment: ... Its operator precedence is also defined as `infixr 0 $`, so it has very high precedence to the right.  It lets you write expressions like `sum $ map (+1) $ filter (> 2) $ map sin [1..100]`.  This would be equivalent to `sum . map (+1) . filter (> 2) . map sin $ [1..100]`.

Comment: Ok good to know, thanks! Could you explain how the movieAvgRating function works as queried in my last comment? I'm struggling to get my head around how it knows what movie it is handling.

Comment: The argument is implicit.  One of the cool things about Haskell is that a function like `movieAvgRating mov = average (ratings mov)` is exactly identical to `movieAvgRating = average . ratings`.  This sort of feature is a significant part of functional programming and higher order functions in general and is known as eta-reduction (eta the greek letter).  You can build functions in this form all the time, the `ratings` function could have been written as `ratings = map snd . mRatings` as well.

Comment: I think I get you! I still have to supply an arguement if i'm calling the function from another function? So if I call `movieAvgRating MOVIE` from some other function, it will just return the average rating?

Comment: It works! Hurray, thanks! I'll bother you with one last thing: Why not have the movie data type as follows: `Movie = Movie Name Year [(Fan,Rating)]` instead of adding mVersions? The reason I can think of is to be specific in case you had other Names, Years etc, am I correct?

Comment: [See my comments in the chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48291/discussion-between-chillo-and-bheklilr)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question first, you can bind to a variable and unpack it simultaneously using `@`:

```
avgRating [(Movie a b mylist@[(fan, rating)])] = …
```

Note also that if you’re not going to be using variables that you unpack, it’s Haskell convention to bind them to `_`:

```
avgRating [(Movie _ _ mylist@[(fan, rating)])] = …
```

This helps readers focus on what’s actually important.

I don’t want to just give you the solution to your recursion problem, because learning to write recursive functions is an important and rewarding part of Haskell programming.  (If you really want me to spoil it for you, let me know in a comment.)  The basic idea, however, is that you need to think about two different cases: a base case (where the recursion stops) and a recursive case.  As an example, consider the built-in `sum` function:

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum [] = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

Here, the base case is when `sum` gets an empty list – it simply evaluates to 0.  In the recursive case, we assume that `sum` can already produce the sum of a smaller list, and we extend it to cover a larger list.

If you’re having trouble with recursion in general, Harold Abelson and Gerald Jay Sussman present a detailed discussion on the topic in [*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), 2nd ed., The MIT Press (Cambridge), 1996, starting on p. 21 ([§§1.1.7–1.2](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1.7)).  It’s in Scheme, not Haskell, but the languages are sufficiently similar – at least at this conceptual level – that each can serve as a decent model for the other.

Comment: No I don't want recursion spoilt for me, but it's the part of haskell i'm finding hardest to pick up. Thanks for the reply, just looking at the sum function is helping me piece it together.